# Getting microphone info with WebAudio API

Tags: web-audio-api

I want to be able to see which microphone WebAudio API picked up when it returns the MediaStream. It would be even better if I could select the microphone when more than one is available.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried, but these guide seems to suggest a way to do it http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-history

Answer (score 3):

There is, but it only works when your page is served securely (i.e. https:// instead of http://).  (this is common with new security-sensitive apis.)

Check out https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/index.html - the select dropdown lets you choose inputs.